# How to fix a TypeError in django related to parsing JSON?

Tags: python, django, json

I get a TypeError displaying in the browser when I run the code below.  The error comes at the last line and says 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable (I am trying to get all the urls for all the items).  However it is odd because in the command line, all the urls in the feed get printed.  Any ideas on why the items are getting printed in the command line but showing an error in the browser?  How do I fix this?

```
#reddit parse
try:
    f = urllib.urlopen("http://www.reddit.com/r/videos/top/.json");
except Exception:
    print("ERROR: malformed JSON response from reddit.com")
reddit_posts = json.loads(f.read().decode("utf-8"))["data"]["children"]
reddit_feed=[]
for post in reddit_posts:
    if "oembed" in post['data']['media']:
        print post["data"]["media"]["oembed"]["url"]
        reddit_feed.append(post["data"]["media"]["oembed"]["url"])  
print reddit_feed
```

## edit

```
if post["data"]["media"]["oembed"]["url"]:
    print post["data"]["media"]["oembed"]["url"]
```

Comment: you could do intermediate prints, before you can access the end object at once. Example: `print post['data']`, `print post['data']['media']` and figure out what is returning a none object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are posts in the returned json with `media=null` so `post['data']['media']` will not have `oembed` field (and hence, `url` field):

```
     {
        "kind" : "t3",
        "data" : {
           "downs" : 24050,
           "link_flair_text" : null,
           "media" : null,
           "url" : "http://youtu.be/aNJgX3qH148?t=4m20s",
           "link_flair_css_class" : null,
           "id" : "rymif",
           "edited" : false,
           "num_reports" : null,
           "created_utc" : 1333847562,
           "banned_by" : null,
           "name" : "t3_rymif",
           "subreddit" : "videos",
           "title" : "An awesome young man",
           "author_flair_text" : null,
           "is_self" : false,
           "author" : "Lostinfrustration",
           "media_embed" : {},
           "permalink" : "/r/videos/comments/rymif/an_awesome_young_man/",
           "author_flair_css_class" : null,
           "selftext" : "",
           "domain" : "youtu.be",
           "num_comments" : 2260,
           "likes" : null,
           "clicked" : false,
           "thumbnail" : "http://a.thumbs.redditmedia.com/xUDtCtRFDRAP5gQr.jpg",
           "saved" : false,
           "ups" : 32312,
           "subreddit_id" : "t5_2qh1e",
           "approved_by" : null,
           "score" : 8262,
           "selftext_html" : null,
           "created" : 1333847562,
           "hidden" : false,
           "over_18" : false
        }
     },
```

---

It also seems to be that your exception message doesn't really fit: there are many kinds of exceptions that can be thrown when `urlopen` blows up, such as `IOError`. It does not check on whether the returned format is valid JSON as your error message imply.

Now, to mitigate the problem, you need to check if `"oembed" in post['data']['media']`, and only if it does can you call `post['data']['media']['oembed']['url']`, notice that I am making the assumption that all `oembed` blob has `url` (mainly because you need an URL to embed a media on reddit).

**UPDATE: 
Namely, something like this should fix your problem:

```
for post in reddit_posts:
    if isinstance(post['data']['media'], dict) \
           and "oembed" in post['data']['media'] \
           and isinstance(post['data']['media']['oembed'], dict) \
           and 'url' in post['data']['media']['oembed']:
        print post["data"]["media"]["oembed"]["url"]
        reddit_feed.append(post["data"]["media"]["oembed"]["url"])
print reddit_feed
```

The reason you have that error is because for some `post`, `post["data"]["media"]` is `None` and so you are basically calling `None["oembed"]` here. And hence the error: `'NoneType' object is not subscriptable`. I've also realized that `post['data']['media']['oembed']` may not be a dict and hence you will also need to verify if it is a dict *and* if `url` is in it.

**Update 2:**

It looks like `data` won't exist sometimes either, so the fix:

```
import json
import urllib

try:
    f = urllib.urlopen("http://www.reddit.com/r/videos/top/.json")
except Exception:
    print("ERROR: malformed JSON response from reddit.com")
reddit_posts = json.loads(f.read().decode("utf-8"))

if isinstance(reddit_posts, dict) and "data" in reddit_posts \
   and isinstance(reddit_posts['data'], dict) \
   and 'children' in reddit_posts['data']:
    reddit_posts = reddit_posts["data"]["children"]
    reddit_feed = []
    for post in reddit_posts:
        if isinstance(post['data']['media'], dict) \
               and "oembed" in post['data']['media'] \
               and isinstance(post['data']['media']['oembed'], dict) \
               and 'url' in post['data']['media']['oembed']:
            print post["data"]["media"]["oembed"]["url"]
            reddit_feed.append(post["data"]["media"]["oembed"]["url"])
    print reddit_feed
```

Comment: I tried the edit that I included in the question above, but it doesn't seem to work as I get the same error.  Any advice on how I actually implement it?

Comment: I still get the same error (argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable) after I include the update code and it's pointing to the new linke with "oembed".  Could it be a problem with how I'm defining reddit_feed?  json.loads(f.read().decode("utf-8"))["data"]["children"], particularly ["data"] and ["children"]?

Comment: @sharataka can you post your new code? The error message has changed from `not subscriptable` to `not iterable` so the it is likely another problem somewhere else.

Comment: I just added the new code in the body of the question.  Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: @sharataka Glad to help! I've updated with the code that should these problems (tested :) )

Comment: Thanks!  It seems to be working for the most part but occasionally I get a TypeError, KeyError: 'data' on the line with reddit_posts = json.loads(f.read().decode("utf-8"))["data"]["children"].  It's odd because sometimes it works and prints the list but sometimes it returns this error.  I am trying to figure out why; it seems that 'data' is always present in the file I'm loading so I'm not sure what is happening in this instance.  Any ideas on this?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18071/discussion-between-kay-zhu-and-sharataka)